# Caption in AMP-Carousel Not Working

Tags: html, css, amp-html, blogspot

I add caption `<div class="caption">` in my amp-carousel beside `amp-img`. When the device turns into mobile, caption looks half hidden.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
<amp-carousel autoplay='' delay='6000' height='340' layout='responsive' type='slides' width='824'>
    <div>
        <div>
            <amp-img alt='' height='240' layout='responsive' src='image-link-here' width='824'/>
            <div class='caption'>
                <p class='text-inside'><em>Pertama</em>, kode yang ditulis dalam membangun website anda harus tervalidasi menggunakan versi HTML, PHP atau CSS kompatibel atau terupdate sehingga mesin pencari dapat melakukan <em>crawling website</em> anda.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <amp-img alt='' height='240' layout='responsive' src='image-link-here' width='824'/>
            <div class='caption'>
                <p class='text-inside'><em>Kedua</em>, loading speed website harus cepat, aman dan <em>mobile friendly</em> (responsive sesuai device yang digunakan semua user).</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <amp-img alt='' height='240' layout='responsive' src='image-link-here' width='824'/>
            <div class='caption'>
                <p class='text-inside'><em>Ketiga</em>, konten website anda harus unik, berguna/bermanfaat bagi visitor dan teroptimasi (on page SEO) atau SEOptin sebut sebagai <b>website UMT</b> (<em>Unik, Manfaat, Teroptimasi</em>).</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <amp-img alt='' height='240' layout='responsive' src='image-link-here' width='824'/>
            <div class='caption'>
                <p class='text-inside'><em>Keempat</em>, tulisan di konten website anda sudah diakui (UMT) oleh website yang relevan (sama niche) atau website terbaik lainnya seperti wikipedia, website edu dsb.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</amp-carousel>
```

In CSS:

```
amp-carousel{
margin-bottom:25px;
}
p.text-inside{
background:#fff;
padding:15px;
border-radius:0px 0px 3px 3px;
border-left:1px solid #DEDEDE;
border-right:1px solid #DEDEDE;
border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;
font-family:&quot;Tahoma&quot;,sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
letter-spacing:1px;
color:#777;
}
p.text-inside em,p.text-inside strong,p.text-inside b{
font-family:&quot;Tahoma&quot;,sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
letter-spacing:1px;
color:#444;
}
```

[Live preview](https://seojateng.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case use `amp-fit-text`

> amp-fit-text : Expands or shrinks its font size to fit the content
>   within the space given to it.

**Code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <link rel="canonical" href="carousel.html">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
   <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
   <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
   <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
   <script async custom-element="amp-fit-text" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-fit-text-0.1.js"></script>
   <style amp-custom>
    amp-carousel{
margin-bottom:25px;
}
p.text-inside{
background:#fff;
padding:15px;
border-radius:0px 0px 3px 3px;
border-left:1px solid #DEDEDE;
border-right:1px solid #DEDEDE;
border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;
font-family:&quot;Tahoma&quot;,sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
letter-spacing:1px;
color:#777;
}
p.text-inside em,p.text-inside strong,p.text-inside b{
font-family:&quot;Tahoma&quot;,sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
letter-spacing:1px;
color:#444;
}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <amp-carousel controls autoplay='' delay='6000' height='440' layout='responsive' type='slides' width='824'>
    <div>
        <div>
            <amp-img alt='' height='240' layout='responsive' src='https://dummyimage.com/840x240/000/f00' width='824'/>
            <amp-fit-text layout="responsive"
      width="824"
      height="200">
            <div class='caption'>
                <p class='text-inside'><em>Pertama</em>, kode yang ditulis dalam membangun website anda harus tervalidasi menggunakan versi HTML, PHP atau CSS kompatibel atau terupdate sehingga mesin pencari dapat melakukan <em>crawling website</em> anda.</p>
            </div>
            </amp-fit-text>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <amp-img alt='' height='240' layout='responsive' src='https://dummyimage.com/840x240/000/0f0' width='824'/>
            <amp-fit-text layout="responsive"
      width="824"
      height="200">
            <div class='caption'>
                <p class='text-inside'><em>Kedua</em>, loading speed website harus cepat, aman dan <em>mobile friendly</em> (responsive sesuai device yang digunakan semua user).</p>
            </div>
            </amp-fit-text>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <amp-img alt='' height='240' layout='responsive' src='https://dummyimage.com/840x240/000/00f' width='824'/>
            <amp-fit-text layout="responsive"
      width="824"
      height="200">
            <div class='caption'>
                <p class='text-inside'><em>Ketiga</em>, konten website anda harus unik, berguna/bermanfaat bagi visitor dan teroptimasi (on page SEO) atau SEOptin sebut sebagai <b>website UMT</b> (<em>Unik, Manfaat, Teroptimasi</em>).</p>
            </div>
            </amp-fit-text>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <amp-img alt='' height='240' layout='responsive' src='https://dummyimage.com/840x240/000/fff' width='824'/>
            <amp-fit-text layout="responsive"
      width="824"
      height="200">
            <div class='caption'>
                <p class='text-inside'><em>Keempat</em>, tulisan di konten website anda sudah diakui (UMT) oleh website yang relevan (sama niche) atau website terbaik lainnya seperti wikipedia, website edu dsb.</p>
            </div>
            </amp-fit-text>
        </div>
    </div>
</amp-carousel>
 </body>
</html>
```

[**Example Here**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RJQEjw)

**For more reference visit:**

1. [amp-fit-text](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-fit-text)
2. [Image Galleries with amp-carousel](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/image_galleries_with_amp-carousel/)

Comment: It leaves a big space above and the below of the `amp-fit-text`. Besides, I see that the property `flex-direction:column` causes big space above the `amp-fit-text`.
when I change the width of the wrapper into bigger, it looks as you suggest, but not in my blog.

Comment: @HermanNz if it is not working on your blog than you can try with "Collapsible Image Captions with amp-bind". also your blog have amp validation issue change layoput with layout

Comment: yes, thanks. sorry for long absent, by the way, you're right, I validated and found typos "layoput" and make them corrected and validated, but the problem still exists even I use amp-bind. All fine in desktop but not in mobile.